# Java specify subclass constructor signature

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

I want to create a method that constructs an object of a class received as a parameter much like the following one:

```
public static <T extends MyAbstractClass> T makeObject(Class<T> c){
    ObjectReceivedFromService orfs = getObjectFromService();
    Constructor<T> constr = c.getConstructor(ObjectReceivedFromService.class);
    return constr.newInstance(orfs);
}
```

Is there a way to make sure that this specific constructor exists on compile time?
I would also like to use an interface instead of an abstract class if possible.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to make sure that `Class<T>` has a no-arg constructor?

Comment: Using interface instead of `MyAbstractClass` should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could expect not the class but the constructor itself as the parameter:

```
public static <T extends AnyInterface> T makeObject(Function<ObjectReceivedFromService, T> constructor){
    ObjectReceivedFromService orfs = getObjectFromService();
    return constructor.apply(orfs);
}
```

To call the Method:

```
makeObject(MyImplementation::new)
```

Finally, any constructor can be used as a function by using the method handle to the constructor.